# Include GAS library as a source

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to include the sources of [BetterLog](https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog/blob/master/Code.gs) lib as a separate file, while keeping its referencing in the same as when added "as a library". How should I wrap it properly?

I've tried different approaches, but no luck. E.g.

BetterLog.gs:

```
BetterLog = () => { 
    // pasted lib src: https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog/blob/master/Code.gs 
};
```

Code.gs:

```
Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet(Settings.currentSpreadsheetID); 
// Calling it in the same way as calling lib-ed version
// However, when using sources, getting the error "BetterLog is null"
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: tricky part is that lib has some "public" methods, e.g.

```
function useSpreadsheet(optKey, optSheetName) {
```

while others are "private":

```
function hasAuth_() {
```

So the challenge is to do as small changes as possible in the lib sources.